# How does the Atiyah Singer index theorem reduce to the Gohberg Krein index theorem for Toeplitz operators?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

If $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbf{T}$ and $T_f$ is the corresponding Toeplitz operator on $H^2$, then the well-known theorem of I. Gohberg and M. Krein asserts that $T_f$ is a Fredholm operator if, and only if, $f$ never vanishes and, in this case,
$$
\operatorname{index}\left(T_f\right)=-\mathrm{wn}(f),
$$
where index $\left(T_f\right)$ is the Fredholm index of $T_f$ and $\mathrm{wn}(f)$ is the winding number of $f$ around the origin.

So I have read several times that the Atiyah-Singer generalizes the Gohberg-Krein index theorem, but I am not sure how the Atiyah-Singer index theorem reduces to the Gohberg-Krein theorem in the case that our manifold is just the unit circle.

So I know there are several different versions of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem, with the heat kernel, and Dirac operator proof being the simplest one. But because the statement itself is so complicated compared to something like the Gohberg-Krein, I'm not sure how one would go backward to get the Gohberg-Krein.

Update: The Atiyah-Singer index theorem Pseudodifferential operator version is given as follows:

For a general elliptic pseudo-differential operator $D$, acting on smooth sections of a closed manifold $M$, the Atiyah-Singer index formula has the following structure. First, the principal symbol of the operator $D$ defines a Chern character $\operatorname{ch}\left(\sigma_D\right)$ which is a cohomology class with compact support in $T M$, the tangent bundle on $M$. In addition, there exists a cohomology class $\operatorname{td}(T M \otimes \mathbb{C})$, called the Todd class, which gives rise to the following integral expression for the index of $D$
$$
\operatorname{ind}(D)=(-1)^n \int_{T M} \operatorname{ch}\left(\sigma_D\right) \operatorname{td}(T M \otimes \mathbb{C})
$$

Comment: In this case, you need Atiyah–Singer for pseudodifferential operators, since elliptic first-order *differential* operators necessarily have index $0$ on odd-dimensional closed manifolds.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić thank you for the reply. So I have updated my post to include the pseudo version of the AS index theorem. So I am still not sure how to translate this to the Gohberg Krein theorem. So, our manifold is S^1, and our vector bundle is probably the trivial bundle S^1 x Complex numbers. Then what would be our pseudo differential operator in this case? Because the symbol of our Psdo must be related to the symbol of our toeplitz operator somehow, and when we plug everything into the right hand side, the winding number should come out.

Comment: I worked this out a long time ago, but don't remember all of the details. First, note that the Toeplitz operator $T_f$ _is_ a pseudo-differential operator of order $0$. Viewing $S^1$ as the unit circle in the complex plane and mucking around with characteristic classes, the right-hand side simplifies down to the formula $\oint_f \frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{dz}{z}$, which we recognize as the winding number.

Comment: @PaulSiegel ok thank you!

Comment: @PaulSiegel may i ask , how does one see that a toeplitz operator is an order 0 pseudo-differential operator? I am not seeing it for some reason.